# exporting a filtered graph in Gephi

Tags: graph, filtering, export-to-csv, gephi

I am trying to export the data table for a filtered graph in Gephi. The initial graph has some 50000 nodes and 70000 edges. I filter it using K-core filter and I want to do some computations on this filtered graph. However, when I export the data table corresponding to it, I get the file same as the original input file. That means the edges and nodes are not filtered from the data file, only hidden in the visualization.

Is there a way to get the filtered data in a csv file from gephi?

Answer (score 6):

Use the "export to new workspace" icon situated in the filters panel. Then you can export it.

Comment: thank. I tried that but gephi just hangs after that and does not respond

Comment: Always check that you work with the latest version of Gephi (0.8.2 beta, click on "check updates" from within Gephi).

Comment: The file does not seem huge so this is surely not memory-related